# Почему возникает зацикливание бинов

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Я пытаюсь реализовать маленький сервер для магазина товаров, но у меня возникла ошибка, делаю все по туториалу, поэтому никак не могу понять возникновение зацикленности. Может у меня глаз замылился и я не вижу бревна. Буду рад любой подсказке. Спасибо!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    @Basic
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/product/edit").hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.name())
//                .antMatchers("/product/edit").hasAuthority(Role.ORGANIZACION.name())
//                .antMatchers("/order").hasRole(Role.CLIENT.name())
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {//security
    boolean save(UserDTO userDTO);
}
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl  implements UserService{
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean save(UserDTO userDto) {
        if(!Objects.equals(userDto.getPassword(), userDto.getMatchingPassword())){
            throw new RuntimeException("Password is not equal");
        }
        User user = User.builder()
                .usernames(userDto.getUsername())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()))
                .email(userDto.getEmail())
                .role(Role.CLIENT)
                .build();
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findFirstByUsernames(username);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with name: " + username);
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsernames(),
                user.getPassword(),
                roles);
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?


2023-03-27T01:07:18.156+03:00 ERROR 4484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

???????
|  securityConfiguration
?     ?
|  userServiceImpl defined in file [C:\Users\amir1\IdeaProjects\bridge-web\project\TestTask\target\classes\com\example\testtask\service\UserServiceImpl.class]
???????


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

Answer (score 1):

По идее дело в том, что конфигу нужен userServiceImpl который вы в него инжектите, а ему самому нужен passwordEncoder, который биндится в конфиге.

Перенесите бинд passwordEncoder в третье место. Например в класс Application